# What exactly is Weinberg's power counting theorem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, propagator

> The massive gravity propagator goes like $\sim \frac{p^2}{m^4}$ at
>   high energies and in this case we cannot apply Weinberg's standard
>   power counting arguments.

I have read something like that in an article but didn't understand what is Weinberg's power counting arguments and how to use them. The original article of Weinberg, with the title *"High-Energy Behavior in Quantum Field Theory"*, is too complicated for me. **Can anybody explain this method in a more simpler way?**

Comment: "apply Weinberg's standard power counting arguments" to do what ?

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the analog of the massive photon. The propagator for this is
$$
\frac{ g^{\mu\nu} - \frac{p^\mu p^\nu}{m^2}  }{ p^2 + m^2 } 
$$
At large energies, this scales like $\frac{p^\mu p^\nu }{m^2 p^2} \sim \frac{1}{m^2}$.

In the same way, the massive graviton propagator takes the general form
$$
\frac{g^{\mu\alpha} g^{\nu\beta} + g^{\mu\beta} g^{\nu\alpha} - \# g^{\mu\nu} g^{\alpha\beta} + \# \frac{ p^\mu p^\alpha }{ m^2 } g^{\nu\beta} + \# \frac{ p^\nu p^\beta }{ m^2 } g^{\mu\alpha}  + \# \frac{ p^\mu p^\nu }{ m^2 } g^{\alpha\beta}  + \# \frac{ p^\alpha p^\beta }{ m^2 } g^{\mu\nu}  + \# \frac{p^\mu p^\nu p^\alpha p^\beta }{ m^4 } }{p^2 + m^2 }   
$$
where $\#$ are numbers whose values I cannot recall off the top of my head. They are fixed by requirements that when contracted with $p_\mu$ or $p_\nu$ or $p_\alpha$ or $p_\beta$ or $g_{\alpha\beta}$ or $g_{\mu\nu}$ it vanishes.

At high energies, this propagator scales like
$$
\frac{p^\mu p^\nu p^\alpha p^\beta }{ p^2 m ^4 } \sim \frac{p^2 }{ m^4 } ~. 
$$

Comment: The q title mentions a theorem?

Comment: The question is not about the behavior of the propagators at high energies, what I wonder is how can we apply Weinberg's power counting theorem and deduce if a theory is renormalizable or not.